# Why is my button disappearing after being clicked

Tags: html, forms, button

My button is acting the way I need it to except when it is clicked on it completely disappears.  Why is it doing this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function randomlinks(){
    var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*6)
    var links=new Array()
    links[0]="https://abantutogether.org/"
    links[1]="https://abantutogether.org/about-us"
    links[2]="https://abantutogether.org/donate"
    links[3]="https://abantutogether.org/get-involved"
    links[4]="https://abantutogether.org/blog"
    links[5]="https://abantutogether.org/contact-us"
    links[6]="https://abantutogether.org/sponsor-a-child"
  
 
     window.open(links[myrandom])
}
</script>
<form>
<input type="image" src="https://i.postimg.cc/43PDgqnZ/Logo-Pix-Teller-1.png"  value="random link!" onClick="randomlinks()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click the button another tab/browser window is opened and the page is being submitted. Is this the behavior you expect?

It sounds weird to me the form submission in this circumstance (there is no `action` attribute set in the `form` TAG) . Maybe you don't want to have this input inside a form, or alternatively you can just avoid the submmit by changing the onclick property as follow:

```
onClick="randomlinks(); return false;"
```